# Undelete 100k mails in Gmail

Tags: thunderbird, gmail, imap, gmail-imap

One of our Gmail accounts has 100k mails in the trash, and all mail in the bin should be recovered.

Mail in the trash will be deleted automatically over time. What is the best way to undelete these mails in one action? I've tried to create an action using `in:trash` as filter, but there is no option to put things back in the inbox, or to undelete them.

I've setup an IMAP account in Thunderbird, but don't see the trash folder there. If that would work, I could undelete from Thunderbird, which would be a good solution I think.

**How can I mass undelete mail in Gmail?**

Comment: By the way, there is an option to send them back to the inbox (or another folder) from the trash. You need to use the [**Move to** button](http://snag.gy/YZB9z.jpg)

Comment: Maybe [this thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/T8Fu-qVVFg4) will help

Comment: You may add that as answer if you want the points (before this question is closed)!

Comment: Actually, I voted to move the question to webapps.SE. I assume my suggestion helped solved your problem? If it did, I'll add an answer.

Comment: Yes, the problem is solved. All mail is restored!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To move your mail from the Trash folder to the Inbox or any other folder, use the **Move to** button:
[image: Move to button]

You can select all the 100K emails in the Trash by selecting all mail on the first page and then clicking on the **Select all xxx messages...** link at the bottom of the page.

This image from [Gmail Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/T8Fu-qVVFg4) illustrates what you need to do:
[image: Select all emails]
<sub>(click on the image to enlarge it)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the Folder subscription Manual

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/thunderbird-and-gmail#w_subscribing-to-folders-and-synchronizing-messages

Section : Subscribing to folders and synchronizing messages

if you subscribe to the Folder, you are able to see it.
If you see it, you can select all (left click and then hold shift press End + arrow down) and drag/drop into the Folder where you would like them to have